# How do I add an ImageView to the root layout?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am following this tutorial into making an app for Android and ran into a problem. Disclaimer: I know next to nothing about Java or Eclipse, so bear with me.

I created a bitmap, which I put into an ImageView(?), and now the tutorial says to add the ImageView to the root_layout, but to be fair, I have no idea what the root_layout is (I Googled some, but couldn't find the right answer). Also, Eclipse gives me the 'layoutroot cannot be resolved or is not a field'-error, which I do not know how to solve. My question then is, how do I get the image to display on the screen? Thanks in advance :-)

Here is my (full) code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ShowImage extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.show_image, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // shows the activity
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_image);

    try {
        // load large image from resources
        Bitmap game_image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.sample_0);
        // create cropped image from loaded image
        Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(game_image, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        // no longer need larger image
        game_image.recycle();

        // create ImageView to display image
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(cropped);

        // add ImageView to root layout
        LinearLayout root =  (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
        root.addView(imageView);
    }
    // catch comes here

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // shows GamePlay-activity after three seconds
            Intent intent = new Intent(ShowImage.this, GamePlay.class);
            ShowImage.this.startActivity(intent);
            ShowImage.this.finish();
        }
    }, 3000);
}
}
```

Added .xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="nl.mprog.projects.nPuzzle10206353.ShowImage" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Wait three seconds..." />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your `activity_show_image`?

Comment: try to use addContentView(imageView) instead root.addView(imageView).

Comment: Where is your activity_show_image.xml file ?

Comment: add it to your xml..<ImageView android:id="@+id/mImageView... etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`root_layout` is basically the existing layout in your xml in which you want to add newly created View.

Assign id `root_layout` to the RelativeLayout in your xml file.

**OR**

Keep a new Layout inside it with `root_layout` id.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="nl.mprog.projects.nPuzzle10206353.ShowImage" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wait three seconds..." />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So now when you use this in Activity:

```
RelativeLayout root =  (RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
root.addView(imageView);
```

`imageView` would be added to that `RelativeLayout` with id `root_layout`

Answer (score 0):

add the imageView to your xml:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/mImageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="solecito"
    android:layout_weight = "1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"  
/>
```

then add it on you onCreate Method

```
ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mImageView);
```

after you can add the image

```
Bitmap bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
im.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.tommymacwilliam.androidwalkthroughapp3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class AndroidWalkthroughApp3 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            // load large image from resources
            Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.puzzle_0);
            // create cropped image from loaded image
            Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(background, 0, 0, 230, 230);
            // no longer need larger image
            background.recycle();

            // create ImageView to display image
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(cropped);

            // add ImageView to root layout
            LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
            root.addView(imageView);

            int screenWidth = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(screenWidth), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            // uh oh.
        }
    }
}
```